# State values displaying but not passing

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux

I have a component that uses componentDidMount where axios maps a json file, putting the values into a new array and then runs setState on those values. This seems to work.

But when I try to pass those values to a child component, I can display the new state values, but they don't pass to the child component. I did notice that when I set the state default state values in the constructor, those values were sent to the child, but not the most recent setState values, so it seems to be calling the child before the setState in componentDidMount and not updating.

So, currently, I have a situation where my constructor sets the defaults 1900/2000

```
constructor (props, context) {
  super(props, context)
    this.state = {
      startDate: 1900,
      endDate: 2000,
      epochs: '',
    }
  }
```

But the logic in componentDidMount, changes these to 1600-1700. Thus, it reads "Timeline: 1600-1700", but passes 1900 & 2000 to TimeLine:

```
return (
    <div className="class-nav">
      Timeline: {this.state.startDate} - {this.state.endDate} 
      <TimeLine
        startDate = {this.state.startDate}
        endDate = {this.state.endDate}
      />
    </div>
)
```

What's the best way to handle this, cause I'm going in circles to no avail.

Thanks

---

Updated with more code:

Here is the componentDidMount...

```
  componentDidMount(){

var epochArray = [];
axios.get('/json/periods.json') // JSON File Path
.then(({ data })=> {
  data.map((epochs) => {
    epochArray[epochs.epoch] = [epochs.start,epochs.end];
    return epochArray;
  });

  this.setState( {
    epochs: epochArray,
    startDate: parseInt(epochArray[this.state.epoch][0],0),
    endDate: parseInt(epochArray[this.state.epoch][1],0),
  });

})
.catch((err)=> {})
}
```

I'm converting the data in the json into an associative array, for easier look up and then using my default epoch value to set the start and end dates. As mentioned above, it does display properly when echoed out in my render, but it doesn't pass down to the TimeLine component.

Comment: show the logic of componentDidMount, I don't know how do you change it and when but probably based on props and if so then you should use not component did mount but componentWillRecieveProps

Comment: More code please

Comment: I don't see default value for `epochs` in constructor why?

Comment: I'd left the epochs out in the initial, hoping to simplify the idea, but I do have it set to epochs: '', in my file. I guess I should just have shown it all.  Also, when I set it to componentWillRecieveProps, it makes the display values also = the default, so       Timeline: {this.state.startDate} - {this.state.endDate} 
shows 1900/2000, and not 1600/1700, so that's interesting, just not what I'm looking for.